# Passing \x00 as arguments in python

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing

i have a problem to deal. I must call a program with  specific arguments, and one of them must be "\x00" and no, it is not a string '\' 'x' '0' '0' it is hex value then it is end of string. I'm on linux and i know that bash doesn't allow you to do it easily. But i tought to use python

```
program = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

where args are:

```
args = ["./input.sh", "test", "\x00", "test" ]
```

Actually I can't figure out a way to do it, or why it doesn't work. I know that in C it is very easy to do but I want understand why I can't with python and if exists a way

Thank you !!

Comment: C won't be able to tell the difference between "\0" and "".